# Is there a name for this kind of state machine?

Tags: architecture, state, finite-state-machine, logic

I'm thinking of a GUI architecture that works like a finite-state machine where there is a set of possible states and a set of possible inputs--or events.

The thing is, some states transition to the next state solely based on the input, but some hold on to the previous input(s) and transition based on the value of the previous input.

For example, let's say there are states `IDLE`, `LOADING`, `LOADED`, and `SELECTED`.
When in `IDLE`, there may or may not be an input `id`, but `id` by itself doesn't cause a transition (or it transitions to itself).
Once the event `screen_load` happens, state transitions to `LOADING`, and on `fetch_success`, state transitions to either `LOADED` or `SELECTED`. If there was an `id` input previously, the state transitions to `SELECTED` immediately, but if no `id` is specified, it transitions to `LOADED`.

Just think of a screen where you have a list of items. If there was no previous selection, only the fetched list of items is shown on screen, but if the user has selected an item in the past (i.e. the user has visited the screen some time in the past and selected an item), the selection is shown as the fetched list of item is shown on screen.

So thinking about this transitioning state model, it's a state machine where certain inputs that were made in the past (e.g. `id`) are stored somewhere and are used later for transition along with the new input (e.g. transitioning from `LOADING` using `fetch_success` + `id`).

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67748628/is-there-a-name-for-this-kind-of-state-machine "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still just a plain old finite state machine.

Let's give a name to the set of values `{IDLE, LOADING, LOADED, SELECTED}`, such as "load states".

The only "catch" is that your state machine's state aren't just the load states, they're the cartestian product of the load states and all possible `id` values. So your states might be like:

- `(load_state: IDLE, id: null)`
- `(load_state: LOADING, id: null)`
- `(load_state: LOADED, id: null)`
- `(load_state: SELECTED, id: null)`
- `(load_state: IDLE, id: 1)`
- `(load_state: LOADING, id: 1)`
- `(load_state: LOADED, id: 1)`
- `(load_state: SELECTED, id: 1)`
- ... and so on, for all values of `id`

Comment: 1. So if I were to draw this as a state diagram, would I have to draw all combinations? 2. There are some combination of values that never occur. For example if the current state is `(load_state: LOADING, id: 1)` and `fetch_success` happens, it never goes to `(LOADED, 1)` because there is an `id`. It must go to `(SELECTED, 1)`.  From this point of view, it would be nice to say there are only four states, and the transitions just depend on previous inputs that are stored in some external memory somewhere. I'm not familiar with automata theory, so please bear with me.

Comment: You can "cross off" states in that cartesian product that aren't valid, so 1. no, you wouldn't only "have to" draw the ones that are valid in your system. 2. External state is possible. Compare this PDA (which enumerates all possible `id` values X the 4 states), with a push-down automata that uses the stack (well, only ever one cell in the stack) to store the `id`. For that PDA, the state space can be reduced down to just the 4 load states.

Comment: Alright. I'll have to look more into PDAs. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that any push down automata with a finite stack (which might not qualify as a PDA technically, IIRC) is no more powerful than a regular FSA. You can enumerate every possible configuration of the stack, multiplied by the states of the PDA (cartesian product) to obtain a set of states that describes every possible state of the PDA. This new state space is guarenteed to be finite, because the PDA's stack, alphabet and state sets were all finite, and thus their cartesian product is finite.